# Reading file contents as input into console

Tags: java, file, input, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a file and then take the contents of that file and have it executed as user input. I am using Scanner for reading files and user input but I am not sure if this is the correct way to go about this since Scanner for input can only System.in and so I am not sure how to pass data from file into input scanner for it to execute in the console. This is my code below for reading class

```
public class readingFile {

Scanner fileReading = new Scanner(new File("somecontent.txt"));
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public readingFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
}

public void startReading()
{
    System.out.println("reading file...");
    while(fileReading.hasNextLine()){
        String data = fileReading.nextLine();
        System.out.println(data);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class readingFile  {
    static String javaFileFullPath = "D://myfolder/Program.java";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        executeJavaFile();
    }

    public static void executeJavaFile() {
        try {
            System.out.println("executing java program from file....");

            Process compileProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c  javac "+javaFileFullPath);
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            System.out.println(compileProcess.exitValue());
            BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(compileProcess.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            inputReader.close();


            Process runProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c  java "+javaFileFullPath);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println(runProcess.exitValue());
            BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(runProcess.getInputStream()));
            String lineStr = "";
            while ((lineStr = inReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(lineStr);
            }
            inReader.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception:"+ex.getMessage());   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this. I just created this program in eclipse and it is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have tried your code but I am only able to print the contents of the file. I want what's inside the file to be passed into the console as user input

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying requirements. This new program will read java file from file system and execute and show output. Please try and let me know in case of any issue. Thanks.

Comment: This is the java program which i executed from this code:

public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.println("Hello World !!");
}
}

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class readingFile  {
    static String javaFileFullPath = "D://myfolder/Program.java";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        executeJavaFile();
    }

    public static void executeJavaFile() {
        try {
            System.out.println("executing java program from file....");

            Process compileProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c  javac "+javaFileFullPath);
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            System.out.println(compileProcess.exitValue());
            BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(compileProcess.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            inputReader.close();


            Process runProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c  java "+javaFileFullPath);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println(runProcess.exitValue());
            BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(runProcess.getInputStream()));
            String lineStr = "";
            while ((lineStr = inReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(lineStr);
            }
            inReader.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception:"+ex.getMessage());   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying requirements. This program will read java file from file system and execute and then show output. Please try and let me know in case of any issue. Thanks.

Comment: This is the program file which i executed:

public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.println("Hello World !!");
}
}